# Compute the limit $\lim_{z \to ia}\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Let $a\in \mathbb R$ and $z=x+iy$. Compute the limit $$\lim_{z \to ia}\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right).$$

My try:
$$\lim_{z \to ia}\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\lim_{z \to ia}\arctan\left(\frac{\operatorname{Im}(z)}{\operatorname{Re}(z)}\right),$$
so
$$\lim_{z \to ia}\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) =
\begin{cases}
\pi/2 , & \text{if $a>0$}, \\[2ex]
-\pi/2 , & \text{if $a<0$} .
\end{cases}$$

Is this correct?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Whether $\;a\in\Bbb R\;$ or a generic $\;a\in\Bbb C\;$ , I don't think that answer is correct. Take into account that $\;\arctan z=\frac1{2i}\log\frac{i+z}{i-z}\;$

Comment: If $x\to 0^{-},$ you get the opposite sign. You need to know $z$ is restricted to the right half-plane to get your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to put it simply, what you want is equivalent to $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,a)}\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$$ . Now consider the path $(x,y)$ parametrized by $(t-a,t)\,,\,t< a$ Then $(x,y)\to (0,a)$ as $t\to a$ .

But $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to a\,\\t<a}\arctan(\frac{t}{t-a})\to-\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $\frac{t}{t-a}\to-\infty$

But if you instead consider the path $(t-a,t)\,\,,t>a$ then also $(x,y)\to(0,a)$ as $t\to a$ but $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to a\\t>a}\arctan(\frac{t}{t-a})\to\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $\frac{t}{t-a}\to\infty$

So the limit does not exist as it's not unique. Notice that I did not impose any condition as to whether $a>0$ or $a<0$ .